# Make sure TD input value doesn't exceed previous TD value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

I'm learning JQuery for a school project and need help trying to traverse through elements.

I have a table that shows balances due and input boxes for a user to put in their own amount to pay the balance. When the user is inputting an amount, I don't want the amount to be more than what is due. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            20.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            30.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="t-currentbalance">
            40.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".forminput").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click change paste", function() {
    var otherAmount = $(this).val();
    var currentBalance = $(this).parent('td').prev('td.balance').html();
    if (otherAmount > currentBalance) {
      alert('You are over the balance amount!');
    }
  });
});
```

When I go over the amount, I keep getting undefined. I changed it to parents and I get a bunch of random data. Any help will be appreciated, thank you so much!~

Answer (score 0):

**1st**: no need for `.each()`

**2nd**: you need to use `parseInt()`

**3rd**: you need to add `input keyup` events as well

See the demo

```js
$('.forminput').on("paste input keyup", function() {
  var otherAmount = parseInt($(this).val());
  var currentBalance = parseInt($(this).parent('td').prev('td.balance').text());
  if (otherAmount > currentBalance) {
    alert('You are over the balance amount!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            20.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            30.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="t-currentbalance">
            40.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this is a `<td>` is really irrelevant to the question or the answer.
You have a `.arow` which contains a `.balance` and a `.otheramount`
When the `.otheramount` changes, you want to get the `.balance` that is within the same `.arow`
Find the closest `.arow` from the current otheramount: `$(this).closest('.arow')`
From that you can find the `.balance` within it: `$(this).closest('.arow').find('.balance')`
It is the text within this that has the current balance:
   `var currentBalance = $(this).closest('.arow').find('.balance').text();`

One issue is you want to treat this as a value, so you can `parseFloat(currentBalance)`

You may also want to check the value as it is being typed, not just when the change event occurs, so add the `keyup` event to the listener, but then you should remove `change`.

Be careful with `parseFloat`, you may want to get the .text() value first and pattern-match it to make sure parseFloat doesn't give you `NaN`.

```js
// Note this does not check for non-numeric input, so parseFloat could botch things.
$(".forminput").on("click paste keyup", function() {
    var otherAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var currentBalance = parseFloat($(this).closest('.arow').find('.balance').text());
    if (otherAmount > currentBalance) {
      alert('You are over the balance amount!');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            20.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            30.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="arow">
        <td class="balance">
            40.00
        </td>
        <td class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here we see that the same thing works even if it's not in a table ... this uses divs and spans.  I mention this because using tables to lay out your content is considered bad form.
You see here that exactly the same code, *no changes*, also works with this markup.  It depends only on the classes, not on which HTML tags are being used.

```js
// Note this does not check for non-numeric input, so parseFloat could botch things.
$(".forminput").on("click paste keyup", function() {
    var otherAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var currentBalance = parseFloat($(this).closest('.arow').find('.balance').text());
    if (otherAmount > currentBalance) {
      alert('You are over the balance amount!');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="arow">
        <span class="balance">
            20.00
        </span>
        <span class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arow">
        <span class="balance">
            30.00
        </span>
        <span class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="arow">
        <span class="balance">
            40.00
        </span>
        <span class="otheramount">
            Other Amount: <input class="forminput" type="number">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```